# Return a different page depending on browser

Tags: html, css, asp.net, cross-browser, asp.net-web-api2

In ASP.NET MVC, it is possible to detect the browser version and thus return a different View for IE8, IE9 and IE10 should you need.

Is this possible in ASP.NET 2 ? In MVC I would detect the user agent string like pseudocode:

```
// Get UserAgent String
if(UserAgent == IE7)
   return View("~/IE7.cshtml");
else if(UserAgent == IE8)
   return View("~/IE8.cshtml");
```

..and so on. Basically, I want to display different HTML and CSS to the user without using conditional statements.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3yekbd5b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks - how, then, do I return a different webpage depending on that code? Sorry for asking a poor question but I've only ever used ASP.NET MVC 4 and am having to do some urgent work on .NET 2

Comment: i have never impelemented such thing but there must be some post avaiable you need to google it, or wait for someone who may answer better